# Django Backend Image not displaying

Tags: python, reactjs, django, django-models

I've tried many ways but nothing works.
I can't find a solution to this issue.
My frontend is React and My backend is  Django.
On browser only show the URL path link of the image instead of an image.
I've tried to add this code to another template and It was working but this one does not work.

[browser display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eliGo.png)

My `settings.py` file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ['django.contrib.staticfiles',]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

My `urls.py` file:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)


if not settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [re_path(r'^.*',
                            TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))]
```

My Model looks like this

```
class Product(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  image = models.ImageField(blank=True)
  description = models.TextField()
  price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
  createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  def __str__(self):
    return f" '{self.name}' "
```

Comment: add your template/html file too

Comment: Hi i notice that you don't have upload_to inside your imagefield please consider adding it.

Answer (score 0):

this is my configuration, in my project React within Django, hope that could help

```
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        BASE_DIR / 'static',
        BASE_DIR / 'frontend/build/static' //this is from react, frontend is the React project's name
    ]


    MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static/media'
    STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles
```

dont forget to add/install corsheader(add it in INSTALLED_APPS also),and whitenoise

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
...]


STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
 path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
 .....
 ]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I'm new to Django. I did everything above but it still does not display an image still show as the path where the image is located e.g. " /media/Database_ER_diagram_example_crows_foot.jpeg" but on my frontend show a new folder call 'build/static' so I put {% load static %} inside the HTML file but still not working.